# Laravel 5.3 PHP Artisan not working PHP Warning: require(bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php)

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 running my project on xampp for ubuntu 
php version 7.0
After downloading laravel 5.3 project when i try to run php artisan it gives me

> [PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/7arefa-app/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/7arefa-app/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17]

I need help

Comment: have you tried with a **composer update**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set permission for the directory **storage & bootstrap/cache?** if not, please run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/
```